# The process android.com.phone has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android

Am doing one application in android.Whenever am trying to run the application am getting the error "The process android.com.phone has stopped unexpectedly" and "The process android.com.mms has stopped unexpectedly".I have searched for the solution but I couldn't find the solution.Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem??

I checked in logcat..The error i got is com.android.phone.phoneApp classnotfound exception

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look in the Error log and LogCat log. You will find more informations there.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and needed some time to find the mistake. Inside my menu class i instantiated a new Class.... it looked like this

```
Class ourClass = Class.forName("package.name.ClassName);
```

But inside my manifest the class has been listed, starting with a lowercase character in "android:name":

```
<activity
        android:name=".className"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Of course, Thorben is right, the LogCat just prints out, the Class couldn't be found, but sometimes a tiny mistake like this can be overlooked.